# What encryption algorithm is used in DPAPI for WP7?

Tags: c#, security, windows-phone-7, cryptography

Do someone of you know what encryption algorithm is used exactly in the [Data Protection API for WP7](http://debugmode.net/2011/10/16/protecting-password-or-any-data-in-windows-phone-7-using-data-protection-api/)?

I've read a few MSDN and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_API) articles on this, but most of them focussed on DPAPI for the pc versions of Windows. I could assume it is 3DES like it is said in [this whitepaper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx), but I hope for AES. Between 2001 and 2011 a lot of things happened to cryptography :)

Any additional information whould be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As near as I can tell DPAPI continues to use the Triple-DES algorithm.

I can find no mention of it changing.

Comment: But you also did not find anything that supports our thesis that it uses Triple-DES? As I said, I can guess its Triple-DES but thats only an assertion then :( I was looking for hard evidences.

Comment: The paper that you linked to asserts that DPAPI uses Triple-DES. That is directly from Microsoft. That is certainly hard evidence. There is not reason to believe it has changed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355

Comment: Here is a presentation from BlackHat 2010 that asserts that DPAPI uses Triple-DES. http://cdn.ly.tl/talks/reversing-dpapi-and-stealing-windows-secrets-offline-slides.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will then assume its also Triple-DES that is used on WP7. However, I wished MS would add this information to its official documentation, just for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

According to Passcape, DPAPI on Windows 7 by default uses the AES256 encryption in the CBC mode, SHA512 for hashing and PBKDF2 as password-based key derivation routine

See http://www.passcape.com/index.php?section=docsys&cmd=details&id=28#14